# Issue accessing RapidAPI with httr / R - Status: 401

Tags: r, http-status-code-401, httr, rapidapi

I am trying to access a RapidAPI with the **httr** package in **R** as follows:

```
library(httr)
url <- "https://extract-news.p.rapidapi.com/v0/article"
queryString <- list(url = "https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/17/21224728/bill-gates-coronavirus-lies-5g-covid-19")
response <- VERB("GET", url, addheaders(x_rapidapi_key ="my-api-key", x_rapidapi_host = "extract-news.p.rapidapi.com"), query = queryString, contenttype("application/octet-stream"))
content(response, "text")
```

I tried accessing other APIs too. However, I keep getting this error message:

```
Status: 401
```

Could you please help me solve this issue?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is probably and issue with your api key. It's probably expired or something else. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Comment: Thanks @dcruvolo! I checked, but could not detect any issue with my api key. Any other idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `content_type()` and `add_headers` instead of `contenttype` and `addheaders` to tell the server what sort of data you are sending. Read more about the VERB method [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.2/topics/VERB).

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://extract-news.p.rapidapi.com/v0/article"

queryString <- list(url = "https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/17/21224728/bill-gates-coronavirus-lies-5g-covid-19")

response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(x_rapidapi-host = 'extract-news.p.rapidapi.com', x_rapidapi-key = '*************************', '), query = queryString, content_type("application/octet-stream"))

content(response, "text")
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue on `R` that returns 401 message. The code you posted is not working, is there any way to tackle this issue?? Many thanks!